# Multi column dropdown formatted text

Tags: php, mysql

My first ever question - new to php...
I have a dropdown/combo box in php with data from MySQL populated by following loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){<br>
    echo 'option value="',$row['ContactID'],'" ',$row['ContactName'],' ----',$row['Phone1'],' ---- ',$row['Email1'],' /option';"
}
```

Chevrons / angle brackets missing in above echo....

Output in the dropdown is something like...

```
xxxxxxxx----yyyy----zzzzzzz
xxxx----yyyyyy----zzzzzzzzzzz
xx----yy----zz
etc.
```

How can I format the 3 column widths?
I would like the output like this....

```
xxxxxxxx yy      zzzzz
xx       yyyy    zzzz
xxxx     yyy     zzzzzzz
```

I spent yesterday playing with printf and sprintf with no luck. I will look up pre

Comment: How can I format the 3 column widths? sorry explain bit more

Comment: i am bit confused can you use three value for one column???,

Comment: You might want to use `<pre>` for using fixed widths?

Comment: @gottliebnotschnabel can he do that what he is doing in the option tag. I dont thats why i am asking. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve. But for this answer I am assuming that you're looking for a well formatted output like this:

```
xxxxxxxx ----   yyyy ----     zzzzzzz
    xxxx ---- yyyyyy ---- zzzzzzzzzzz
      xx ----     yy ----          zz
```

You should have a look at the [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) (respectively [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)) function. With the help of this function, you can format strings. In your example, this could work like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    echo '<option value="' . $row['ContactID'] . '">' .
             sprintf("%10s", $row['ContactName']) .
             sprintf("%10s", $row['Phone1']) .
             sprintf("%10s", $row['Email1']) .
         '</option>';
}
```

This fills up your output with blank spaces until the string has a length of 10 characters (Change the `10` in `%10s` to your desired length). The minimum length should be at least equal the possible maximum length of your output strings.

But keep in mind that multiple blank spaces in HTML are ignored, unless you use explicit blank spaces (`&nbsp;`) or you put the content into a tag that preserves blank spaces, like `<pre></pre>`. Not sure if this is necessary within a dropdown menu.